# Tensorflow, FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialised value Variable_3

Tags: macos, tensorflow

When I run my code I get an error that says:

```py
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_3
```

I have no variable in my code called Variable_3.

Tracing back the error I can see that it occurs on the return of this function:

```py
def new_biases(length):
    return tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.05, shape=[length]))
```

The trace then jumps from that function to internal files from the TensorFlow framework:

```py
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 199, in __init__
expected_shape=expected_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 330, in _init_from_args
self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1400, in identity
result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Identity", input=input, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_3
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?
Thanks!

Comment: we need more of your code to know what's happening. The name Variable_3 is normal, it's the name of your 3rd or 4th variable created without specifying a custom name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not calling global_variables_initializer().  You need code like `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` where `sess` is your Session.  This should be at a point in your code where all TensorFlow Variables have already been declared.